# how to get Eclipse Workspace Location URI

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a plugin, which passes the location URI of current workspace to other method.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
```

I am very new to Eclipse PDE. What method returns the URI location of workspace. for Ex if the workspace is C:\Eclipse\Workspace. i need the path C:\Eclipse\Workspace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need workspace URL? The only thing you may rely is that it will contain .metadata folder - everything else may be located elsewhere:

1. Projects can be created outside of the workspace.
2. Workspace files/folders may actually be a links to external resources (that might not even be local files).

My recommendation:

1. If you want to find some resources - use IResource::getLocationURI and check that it is a local file (you may download the content if the URL is EFS)
2. If you want to access your plugin data (that is in .metadata) use Plugin.getStateLocation
3. If you still think you need workspace root - Platform.getInstanceLocation

Comment: +1. Normal Eclipse plugins should always work without knowledge of absolut file system locations.

Answer (score 1):

Get the absolute file system path of any resource:

```
IResource.getLocation()
```