# How to get the file location using the file path?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

In Eclipse, when I right click on the file I want to input from in my project, it shows two things: 
path:  /SWT/src/data.txt
location: C:\Users\Yoshikawa\workspace\SWT\src\data.txt

Is there any way I can get the location (C:\Users\Yoshikawa\workspace\SWT\src\data.txt) is I know just the path (/SWT/src/data.txt) ?

Ex.

```
public String ReadFile(String file_path) {
        //Search current project directory 

            return file_location
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692636/how-to-get-eclipse-workspace-location-uri

Answer (score 3):

```
public String readFile(String file_path){
  File f = new File(file_path);
  return f.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to create a File object based on the file_path and then run the method getAbsolutePath() method of the File class.
h
You can read up more on this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html
Hopefully this works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java [Path Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use File.getAbsolutePath or File.getCanonicalPath. They are not the same, see the difference

```
    String relativePath = "../1.txt";
    System.out.println(new File(relativePath).getCanonicalPath());
    System.out.println(new File(relativePath).getAbsolutePath());
```

output

```
D:\workspace1\1.txt
D:\workspace1\x\..\1.txt
```

see java.io.File API for details